# "Clear is not recognized as an internal or external command" in gVim

Tags: windows, vim, cmd

I'm trying to compile and run C and CPP programs in gVim. I'm on Windows. How could I fix it?

`:command  Runcpp !clear;g++ % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>`

`:command  Runc   !clear;gcc % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

[`clear`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/clear) is a Unix terminal command. For windows the command is [`cls`](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html).

Answer (score 0):

**This will clear all the previously entered commands.**

For windows CMD use

```
cls
```

For Unix/MAC/Linux terminal use

```
clear
```